# How to define an interface which matches certain type objects?

Tags: typescript

In a piece of code I'd like to do a sort of metaprogramming, and I want to define a function to which I can pass in certain *types* as arguments (so not instances of a type, but the types themselves).

And I want to restrict the accepted types to be a certain class or its descendants.

I'm trying to achieve this with the following code:

```
class ABase {}
class AConc extends ABase {}

class B {}

interface IAClass {
  new(): ABase;
}

function meta(AT: IAClass) {
  console.log('foo');
}

// This gives an error, as it should.
meta(5);

// These compile, this is the usage I want.
meta(ABase);
meta(AConc);

// These compile, but this is what I don't want to allow.
// I only want to be able to pass in types deriving from ABase.
meta(B);
meta(Array);
meta(Number);
```

The first call, `meta(5)` gives me a compiler error, rightfully so. On the other hand, the last 3 calls compile without any errors, despite that the types passed in are not deriving from `ABase`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You want [nominal typing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202), but it is not supported yet by typescript.

Typescript team recommends to use `__brand` field on your classes:

```
class ABase {private __brand: ABase}
```